# How to trigger/force update a Svelte component

Tags: svelte

I am trying to get my head around the svelte 3 reactivity thing...

1. I wanted to force refreshing a UI on a button click. I am using a custom component `AsyncFetcher` that accepts HTTP post data, and returns `data` object (http post result) for its slot.
2. I wanted to have a disable functionality. So when the "Disable" button is clicked an http api is called followed by a refresh of the data view.

```html
<script>
    export let id

    function onDisable() {
        fetch('disable-api-url', {id: id})
        // Then ??
        // What to do after the fetch call, to refresh the view
    }
</script>

<AsyncFetcher postParam={id} let:data>
    {data.name}

    <button on:click={??}>Refresh</button>
    <button on:click={onDisable}>Disable Item</button>
</AsyncFetcher>
```

I tried doing `on:click={() => id=id}` to trick it to refresh to no avail. If `id` would have been an object rather than string `id={...id}` would have worked, which unfortunately, is not the case here.

What would be a correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using a component to manage fetches is very unconventional. Typically you'd fetch data inside `onMount`, or in an event handler:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let initialData;
  let otherData;

  onMount(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('some-url');
    initialData = await res.json();
  });

  async function update() {
    const res = await fetch('some-other-url');
    otherData = await res.json();
  }
</script>

{#if initialData}
  <p>the data is {initialData.something}</p>
{/if}

<button on:click={update}>update</button>
```

Answer (score 14):

While [Rich Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56893678/235704) gives a completely serviceable answer, here's a solution for forcing Svelte to update a component to reflect **an external change** of its data ([also posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59332462/235704)).

**main.js**; vanilla from the examples online, no special changes:

```
import App from './App.svelte';

var app = new App({
    target: document.body
});

export default app;
```

**index.html**; Note `window.neek = {...}`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Svelte app</title>
    <script>
        window.neek = { nick: true, camp: { bell: "Neek" }, counter: 0 };
    </script>
    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.svelte**; Note `$: notneek = window.neek` and `window.neek.update = ...`:

```
<script>
    let name = 'world';
    $: notneek = window.neek;

    function handleClick() {
        notneek.counter += 1;
    }

    window.neek.update = function () {
        notneek = notneek;
    }
</script>

<h1>Hello { notneek.camp.bell }!</h1>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {notneek.counter} {notneek.counter === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

Since the `update` function is within the scope of `App.svelte`, it is able to force the re-render when called via `window.neek.update()`. This setup uses `window.neek.counter` for the internal data utilized by the button (via `notneek.counter`) and allows for the deep properties (e.g. `neek.camp.bell = "ish"`) to be updated outside of the component and reflected once `neek.update()` is called.

In the console, type `window.neek.camp.bell = "Bill"` and note that `Hello Neek!` has not been updated. Now, type `window.neek.update()` in the console and the UI will update to `Hello Bill!`.

Best of all, you can be as granular as you want within the `update` function so that only the pieces you want to be synchronized will be.

Answer (score 7):

To fetch data use the [await block](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks):

```html
<script>
    async function fetchData() {
        const res = await fetch('/api')
        const data = await res.json()

        if (res.ok) {
            return data
        } else {
            throw new Error(data)
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

{#await fetchData}
    <p>Fetching...</p>
{:then data}
    <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
{:catch error}
    <div class="error">{error.message}</div>
{/await}
```

To refresh the data you need to trigger a rerender by updating a piece of related state, since this will rerun the await block. You can trigger a rerender by storing the fetch function in a piece of state and reassigning it when the refresh button is clicked:

```html
<script>
    async function fetchData() {
        const res = await fetch('/api')
        const data = await res.json

        if (res.ok) {
            return data
        } else {
            throw new Error(data)
        }
    }

    let promise = fetchData()
</script>

<style>
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<button on:click="{() => {promise = fetchdata()}}">Refresh</button>

{#await promise}
    <p>Fetching...</p>
{:then data}
    <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
{:catch error}
    <div class="error">{error.message}</div>
{/await}
```

Comment: Wow! this was an awesome answer.  I just refactored my code from onMount() to this and it worked right away.  Such a more beautiful solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a somewhat hacky solution for forcing a rerender of a component not dependent on external data:

```
<script>
    // Await immediately resolved promise to react to value change.
    const forceUpdate = async (_) => {};
    let doRerender = 0;
</script>
{#await forceUpdate(doRerender) then _}
    <ForcedToRerender on:click={() => doRerender++} />
{/await}
```

I tried to find a more "native" solution, but this is what I ended up with.
REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/2dc5c7ca82bc450f8f7dd25d2be577b1?version=3.43.0

Comment: This worked perfectly for my use case. I had a list of items and I wanted to do something on a ctrl+click, but on OSX that brings up a context menu, so I had to use `on:contextmenu|preventDefault` but then my UI did not update, even though the state was being set. Using this and adding a `doRerender++` to my contextmenu handler works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I did this (made the component disappear and reappear with a timer):

```
<script>
    import ForcedToRerender from './ForcedToRerender.svelte'
    let visible = true
    let rerender = () =>
    {
        visible=false
        setTimeout(()=>{visible = true}, 100)
    }
</script>
{#if visible}
    <ForcedToRerender />
{/if}
<button on:click={rerender}>Rerender</button>
```

ForcedToRerender.svelte:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte'
    let num = 0
    let rnd = () => num = Math.random()
    onMount(rnd)
</script>
<div on:click={rnd}>
    {num}
</div>
```

This works, as you can see [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b62b316a4e44825b316644a751c0b47?version=3.43.1).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

in my case, svelte did not flush the output,
cos i blocked the javascript event loop by running a benchmark at 100% cpu

in this case, the trick is to manually unblock the event loop with `await sleep(10)`

```html
<script>
  function sleep(millisec = 0) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(_ => resolve(), millisec);
    });
  };
  let result = '';
  async function runBenchmark() {
    for (let step = 0; step < 10; step++) {

      // this needs 100% cpu, so no time for svelte render
      cpuburn(); result += `${step}: 1.234 sec\n`;

      // unblock the JS event loop, so svelte can render
      await sleep(10);
    }
  }
</script>

<pre>{result}</pre>
```

[here](https://svelte.dev/repl/93c2ea8b3161445198ea55307b8216af) is a repl (but currently it triggers a bug in the repl runtime)

solving this with synchronous function calls is probably not possible
(something like a `$$svelte.forceTickSync()`)

Answer (score 1):

The key (no pun intended) to make a component fully reload, and not just update the inside values, is to use `{#key value_to_watch}` like:

```
{#key category_on}
<Testone a={category_on} />
{/key}
```

If `category_on` changes the `<Testone/>` component is fully reloaded
[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c80c0647fdb747358fc7f611dc7bca1d?version=3.28.0)