# Sapper/Svelte update state inside a component after another component is done posting

Tags: sapper, svelte-3

I'm aware of [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891190/how-to-trigger-force-update-a-svelte-component) but still not able to apply it in my situation.

I'm using sapper and have two components. Component2 is to create options or category for a menu. Component1 display the menu with all the options/categories created. Also, component1 includes the component2 in its body.

My issue is when I use component1 and hit save, everything is working(inputs data saved to db) now component1 needs to reflect the new option/category that was just created but it is not aware of the changes. How do I make my component1 (which display all the categories) aware of the changes/update/newcategory once I click save in component2?

Component2 code:
createcategoy.js is working fine and post the data to my db so it is not an issue.

```
<script>
...code to get locationid unrelated to my issue

function createcategory(event){
  let categoryorder = event.target.categoryorder.value
  let categoryname = event.target.categoryname.value
  let categorydescription= 
   event.target.categorydescription.value

 
  fetch('createCategory', {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials : 'include',
  headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-type' : 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
  
  location_id : locationid,
  category_order : categoryorder,
  category_name : categoryname,
  category_description :categorydescription
  })
  }).then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
  console.log("All Is Well. Category created 
      successfully")
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

  
  }

</script>
html form...
```

Now here is component1 which display locations and each location has its own categories created by component2:

```
  <script>     
     import { onMount } from 'svelte';
     import { goto } from '@sapper/app';
     import Createcategory from './createCategory.svelte'

     let locations = []
     onMount(async () => {

     fetch('menubuilder', {
     method: 'POST',
     credentials : 'include',
     headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-type' : 'application/json'
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({

     })
     }).then(response => response.json())
     .then(responseJson => {
     locations = responseJson.info
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error));

     }) //onMount fn
   
   </script>  

    <h1> Menu Builder </h1>
         
    <dl>
    
      {#each locations as location}

  
       
        <br>
    <h1>{location.locationname} </h1>
        <p>{location._id} </p>
          

   <!-- This is component2 where I use to create new 
      category-->
  <Createcategory locationname= 
  {location.locationname} locationid={location._id}/>
  </dt>
  
  
  <dd> 
            
     {#each location.locationcategories as item}
     <div >       
       <p>{item.categoryname} </p>: 
       {item.categorydescription}
       
     </div>
     {/each}
      
        
  
  {/each}

</dl>
```

Now, my only struggle is with how sapper/svelte state works. How do I make component1 update it is state/dom when I submit the component2 that creates the category.

I read the reactivity section in the documentation, the locations variable is assigned inside component1 but component2 is the one responsible for creating the new category.

So, what should I do to update component1 (locations variable and its dom) when component2 save the category to db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways to do this:

1. **raise an event** after posting the new category, your new workflow will be something like:

Component2 pushes to the server
Component2 raises an event `categoryAdded` with as payload the category.
Component1 reacts to this event by appending the given category to it's array.

Or, an in my opinion better approach:

2. add your categories in a **store** that is outside both components.

Component1 will simply display the contents of the store.
Component2 will push new items to the store.

The store itself, will be responsible for getting/pushing the data from and to the server.
This has the two extra benefits:

- The components are only concerned with displaying categories and do not care where they come from or where they go.
- You can easily change the way categories are stored, which endpoint it uses, ...

Comment: I went with the store. As you said, it frees the components to just display the data and don't care how the data is updated. Thanks.